# PHP: replace invalid characters in utf-8 string in

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

How replace (use regex in PHP5) invalid characters in utf-8 string on white space characters?

Comment: What do you want to do? get rid of white space? or utf-8 characters?
Give an example.

Comment: getting rid of UTF-8 characters is easy: `$text = '';` :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use iconv

```
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);
```

see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Cheers

Comment: This didn't work for me. invalid characters stayed. just like it didn't work for bobef. it just doesn't do the job.

Comment: This worked for me. Source file was downloaded CSV of SBA franchise codes, which I manually formatted to JSON to be used in a Laravel seeder. But even though my formatted file passed JSON validation, there were hidden, invalid UTF-8 characters still in the file that PHP couldn't decode.

Comment: I've not yet debugged into the details but iconv as well as mb_convert do not solve the issue with json_encode()
It might help in many cases, not in all.

Answer (score 8):

With **mbstring** you can do:

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

Will work as you want (replace invalid characters by whitespaces), but doesn't seem to work if you want to substitute invalid characters with something else, like `?`.

See: [Replacing invalid UTF-8 characters by question marks, mbstring.substitute_character seems ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215050/replacing-invalid-utf-8-characters-by-question-marks-mbstring-substitute-charac)

Answer (score 3):

The iconv was not working my case (as other solutions) so I found mine here in the part for "Character validation":

http://webcollab.sourceforge.net/unicode.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have come across the cursed ‘Invalid Character‘ error while using PHP’s XML or JSON parser then you may be interested in this.

Unfortunately, PHP’s XML and JSON parsers do not ignore non-UTF8 characters, but rather they stop and throw a rather unhelpful error. I found the below code form net and work excellently for me..

```
//reject overly long 2 byte sequences, as well as characters above U+10000 and replace with ?
$some_string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x10\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x19\x7F]'.
 '|[\x00-\x7F][\x80-\xBF]+'.
 '|([\xC0\xC1]|[\xF0-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF]*'.
 '|[\xC2-\xDF]((?![\x80-\xBF])|[\x80-\xBF]{2,})'.
 '|[\xE0-\xEF](([\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]))|(?![\x80-\xBF]{2})|[\x80-\xBF]{3,})/S',
 '?', $some_string );

//reject overly long 3 byte sequences and UTF-16 surrogates and replace with ?
$some_string = preg_replace('/\xE0[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]'.
 '|\xED[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]/S','?', $some_string );
```

Comment: doesn't solve the issue with json_encode.
it reports some valid UTF8 also as invalid, sadly without giving a clue what the issue is.