# Replacing invalid UTF-8 characters by question marks, mbstring.substitute_character seems ignored

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, mbstring

I would like to replace invalid UTF-8 chars with quotation marks (PHP 5.3.5).

So far I have this solution, but invalid characters are removed, instead of being replaced by '?'.

```
function replace_invalid_utf8($str)
{
  return mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
}

echo mb_substitute_character()."\n";

echo replace_invalid_utf8('éééaaaàààeeÃ©')."\n";
echo replace_invalid_utf8('eeeaaaaaaeeÃ©')."\n";
```

Should output:

```
63 // ASCII code for '?' character
???aaa???eé // or ??aa??eé
eeeaaaaaaeeé
```

But currently outputs:

```
63
aaaee // removed invalid characters
eeeaaaaaaeeé
```

Any advice?

Would you do it another way (using a `preg_replace()` for example?)

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use **mb_convert_encoding()** or **htmlspecialchars()**'s **ENT_SUBSTITUTE** option since PHP 5.4. Of cource you can use **preg_match()** too. If you use intl, you can use **[UConverter](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uconverter)** since PHP 5.5.

Recommended substitute character for invalid byte sequence is **U+FFFD**. see "[3.1.2 Substituting for Ill-Formed Subsequences](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Substituting_for_Ill_Formed_Subsequences)" in UTR #36: Unicode Security Considerations for the details.

When using **mb_convert_encoding()**, you can specify a substitute character by passing Unicode code point to **mb_substitute_character()** or **mbstring.substitute_character** directive. The default character for substitution is ? (QUESTION MARK - U+003F).

```
// REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD)
mb_substitute_character(0xFFFD);

function replace_invalid_byte_sequence($str)
{
    return mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
}

function replace_invalid_byte_sequence2($str)
{
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8'));
}
```

**UConverter** offers both procedual and object-oriented API.

```
function replace_invalid_byte_sequence3($str)
{
    return UConverter::transcode($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
}

function replace_invalid_byte_sequence4($str)
{
    return (new UConverter('UTF-8', 'UTF-8'))->convert($str);
}
```

When using **preg_match()**, you need pay attention to the range of bytes for avoiding the vulnerability of UTF-8 non-shortest form. the range of trail bytes change depending on  the range of lead bytes.

```
lead byte: 0x00 - 0x7F, 0xC2 - 0xF4
trail byte: 0x80(or 0x90 or 0xA0) - 0xBF(or 0x8F)
```

you can refer to the following resources for checking the byte range.

1. "[Syntax of UTF-8 Byte Sequences](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-4)" in RFC 3629
2. "[Table 3-7.  Well-Formed UTF-8 Byte Sequences](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch03.pdf)" in the Unicode Standard 6.1
3. "[Multilingual form encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.en.php)" in W3C Internationalization"

The byte range table is the below.

```
      Code Points    First Byte Second Byte Third Byte Fourth Byte
  U+0000 -   U+007F   00 - 7F
  U+0080 -   U+07FF   C2 - DF    80 - BF
  U+0800 -   U+0FFF   E0         A0 - BF     80 - BF
  U+1000 -   U+CFFF   E1 - EC    80 - BF     80 - BF
  U+D000 -   U+D7FF   ED         80 - 9F     80 - BF
  U+E000 -   U+FFFF   EE - EF    80 - BF     80 - BF
 U+10000 -  U+3FFFF   F0         90 - BF     80 - BF    80 - BF
 U+40000 -  U+FFFFF   F1 - F3    80 - BF     80 - BF    80 - BF
U+100000 - U+10FFFF   F4         80 - 8F     80 - BF    80 - BF
```

How to replace invalid byte sequence without breaking valid characters is shown in "[3.1.1 Ill-Formed Subsequences](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Ill-Formed_Subsequences)" in UTR #36: Unicode Security Considerations and "[Table 3-8. Use of U+FFFD in UTF-8 Conversion](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch03.pdf)" in The Unicode Standard.

The Unicode Standard shows an example:

```
before: <61    F1 80 80  E1 80  C2    62    80    63    80    BF    64  >
after:  <0061  FFFD      FFFD   FFFD  0062  FFFD  0063  FFFD  FFFD  0064>
```

Here is the implementation by **preg_replace_callback()** according to the above rule.

```
function replace_invalid_byte_sequence5($str)
{
    // REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD)
    $substitute = "\xEF\xBF\xBD";
    $regex = '/
      ([\x00-\x7F]                       #   U+0000 -   U+007F
      |[\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]            #   U+0080 -   U+07FF
      | \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]       #   U+0800 -   U+0FFF
      |[\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} #   U+1000 -   U+CFFF
      | \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]       #   U+D000 -   U+D7FF
      | \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}    #  U+10000 -  U+3FFFF
      |[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}         #  U+40000 -  U+FFFFF
      | \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2})   # U+100000 - U+10FFFF
      |(\xE0[\xA0-\xBF]                  #   U+0800 -   U+0FFF (invalid)
      |[\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]    #   U+1000 -   U+CFFF (invalid)
      | \xED[\x80-\x9F]                  #   U+D000 -   U+D7FF (invalid)
      | \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]?      #  U+10000 -  U+3FFFF (invalid)
      |[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{1,2}       #  U+40000 -  U+FFFFF (invalid)
      | \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]?)     # U+100000 - U+10FFFF (invalid)
      |(.)                               # invalid 1-byte
    /xs';

    // $matches[1]: valid character
    // $matches[2]: invalid 3-byte or 4-byte character
    // $matches[3]: invalid 1-byte

    $ret = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use($substitute) {

        if (isset($matches[2]) || isset($matches[3])) {

            return $substitute;

        }
    
        return $matches[1];

    }, $str);

    return $ret;
}
```

You can compare byte directly and avoid preg_match's restriction about byte size by this way.

```
function replace_invalid_byte_sequence6($str) {

    $size = strlen($str);
    $substitute = "\xEF\xBF\xBD";
    $ret = '';

    $pos = 0;
    $char;
    $char_size;
    $valid;

    while (utf8_get_next_char($str, $size, $pos, $char, $char_size, $valid)) {
        $ret .= $valid ? $char : $substitute;
    }

    return $ret;
}

function utf8_get_next_char($str, $str_size, &$pos, &$char, &$char_size, &$valid)
{
    $valid = false;

    if ($str_size <= $pos) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($str[$pos] < "\x80") {

        $valid = true;
        $char_size =  1;

    } else if ($str[$pos] < "\xC2") {

        $char_size = 1;

    } else if ($str[$pos] < "\xE0")  {

        if (!isset($str[$pos+1]) || $str[$pos+1] < "\x80" || "\xBF" < $str[$pos+1]) {

            $char_size = 1;

        } else {

            $valid = true;
            $char_size = 2;

        }

    } else if ($str[$pos] < "\xF0") {

        $left = "\xE0" === $str[$pos] ? "\xA0" : "\x80";
        $right = "\xED" === $str[$pos] ? "\x9F" : "\xBF";

        if (!isset($str[$pos+1]) || $str[$pos+1] < $left || $right < $str[$pos+1]) {

            $char_size = 1;

        } else if (!isset($str[$pos+2]) || $str[$pos+2] < "\x80" || "\xBF" < $str[$pos+2]) {

            $char_size = 2;

        } else {

            $valid = true;
            $char_size = 3;

       }

    } else if ($str[$pos] < "\xF5") {

        $left = "\xF0" === $str[$pos] ? "\x90" : "\x80";
        $right = "\xF4" === $str[$pos] ? "\x8F" : "\xBF";

        if (!isset($str[$pos+1]) || $str[$pos+1] < $left || $right < $str[$pos+1]) {

            $char_size = 1;

        } else if (!isset($str[$pos+2]) || $str[$pos+2] < "\x80" || "\xBF" < $str[$pos+2]) {

            $char_size = 2;

        } else if (!isset($str[$pos+3]) || $str[$pos+3] < "\x80" || "\xBF" < $str[$pos+3]) {

            $char_size = 3;

        } else {

            $valid = true;
            $char_size = 4;

        }

    } else {

        $char_size = 1;

    }

    $char = substr($str, $pos, $char_size);
    $pos += $char_size;

    return true;
}
```

The test case is here.

```
function run(array $callables, array $arguments)
{
    return array_map(function($callable) use($arguments) {
         return array_map($callable, $arguments);
    }, $callables);
}
    
$data = [
    // Table 3-8. Use of U+FFFD in UTF-8 Conversion
    // http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch03.pdf)
    "\x61"."\xF1\x80\x80"."\xE1\x80"."\xC2"."\x62"."\x80"."\x63"
    ."\x80"."\xBF"."\x64",

    // 'FULL MOON SYMBOL' (U+1F315) and invalid byte sequence
    "\xF0\x9F\x8C\x95"."\xF0\x9F\x8C"."\xF0\x9F\x8C"
];

var_dump(run([
    'replace_invalid_byte_sequence', 
    'replace_invalid_byte_sequence2',
    'replace_invalid_byte_sequence3',
    'replace_invalid_byte_sequence4',
    'replace_invalid_byte_sequence5',
    'replace_invalid_byte_sequence6'
], $data));
```

As a note, **mb_convert_encoding** has a bug that breaks s valid character just after invalid byte sequence or remove invalid byte sequence after valid characters without adding **U+FFFD**.

```
$data = [
    // U+20AC
    "\xE2\x82\xAC"."\xE2\x82\xAC"."\xE2\x82\xAC",
    "\xE2\x82"    ."\xE2\x82\xAC"."\xE2\x82\xAC",

    // U+24B62
    "\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2"."\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2"."\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2",
    "\xF0\xA4\xAD"    ."\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2"."\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2",
    "\xA4\xAD\xA2"."\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2"."\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2",

    // 'FULL MOON SYMBOL' (U+1F315)
    "\xF0\x9F\x8C\x95" . "\xF0\x9F\x8C",
    "\xF0\x9F\x8C\x95" . "\xF0\x9F\x8C" . "\xF0\x9F\x8C"
];
```

Although **preg_match()** can be used intead of **preg_replace_callback**, this function has a limition on bytesize. See bug report [#36463](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36463) for details. You can confirm it by the following test case.

```
str_repeat('a', 10000)
```

Finally, the result of my benchmark is following.

```
mb_convert_encoding()
0.19628190994263
htmlspecialchars()
0.082863092422485
UConverter::transcode()
0.15999984741211
UConverter::convert()
0.29843020439148
preg_replace_callback()
0.63967490196228
direct comparision
0.71933102607727
```

The benchmark code is here.

```
function timer(array $callables, array $arguments, $repeat = 10000)
{

    $ret = [];
    $save = $repeat;

    foreach ($callables as $key => $callable) {

        $start = microtime(true);

        do {
    
            array_map($callable, $arguments);

        } while($repeat -= 1);

        $stop = microtime(true);
        $ret[$key] = $stop - $start;
        $repeat = $save;

    }

    return $ret;
}

$functions = [
    'mb_convert_encoding()' => 'replace_invalid_byte_sequence',
    'htmlspecialchars()' => 'replace_invalid_byte_sequence2',
    'UConverter::transcode()' => 'replace_invalid_byte_sequence3',
    'UConverter::convert()' => 'replace_invalid_byte_sequence4',
    'preg_replace_callback()' => 'replace_invalid_byte_sequence5',
    'direct comparision' => 'replace_invalid_byte_sequence6'
];

foreach (timer($functions, $data) as $description => $time) {

    echo $description, PHP_EOL,
         $time, PHP_EOL;

}
```

Comment: Actually not replacing with `U+FFFD` is fine depending on your use case. While it [*"joins characters that would have been separated"*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Substituting_for_Ill_Formed_Subsequences), that isn't an issue when your code is already hardened against such mal-input from users.