# Should i refactor all my framework to use mbstring functions?

Tags: php, utf-8, multibyte

I currently use `mbstring.func_overload = 7` to get working with UTF-8 charset.

I am thinking to refactor all func call to use `mb_*` functions.

Do you think this is necessarily, or with PHP 6 or newer version the multibyte problem will be solved in another way?

Comment: It depends on what you do. If the strings you are working on are all plain ASCII characters, it doesn't matter. For what uses exactly are you thinking to refactor to `mb_`?

Comment: for string that are utf-8 (of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for string that are utf-8 (of course)

Yes, *of course*. There are many things you can do with strings though. UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII. If you only want to operate on the ASCII characters of a string, it may or may not make a difference. It depends on *what you need to do* with your strings.

If you want a direct answer: **No**, you should not refactor every function to an `mb_` function, because it's likely overkill. Should you check your use cases whether a multi-byte UTF-8 string may impact results and refactor accordingly? Yes.

Answer (score 4):

Not recommended if you are using the libraries other people create. Here are three reasons.

1. Overloading can break the behaviors of the libraries that don't expect overloading.
2. Your framework can be broken in the environments without overloading.
3. Depending on overloading decreases the prospective users of your framework because of 2

Good example of 1. is miscaliculation of bytesize in HTTP **Content-Length** field by using **strlen**. The cause is that the overloaded **strlen** function does not return the number of **bytes** but number of **characters**. You can see real world issues in [CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/283) and [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2098).

**Edit:**
deprecating mbstring.func_overload is under consideration in PHP 5.5 or 5.6 (from [mbstring maintainer's mail](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=133548185505478) in 2012 April). So now you **should** avoid mbstring.func_overload.

The recommended policy of handling mutibyte characters for various platforms is to use mbstring or intl or iconv directlly. If you really need fallback functions for handling multibyte characters, use **function_exists()**.

You can see the cases in **Wordpress** and **MediaWiki**.

1. WordPress: [wp-includes/compact.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/compat.php)
2. MediaWiki: [Fallback Class](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classFallback.html)

Some of CMSes like **Drupal** ([unicocde.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!unicode.inc/8)) introduce mutibyte abstraction layer.

I think the abstraction layer is not good idea.
The reason is that the number of handling multibyte functions needed in a lot of case is under 10 and umultibyte functions are easy to use and decrease perfomance for switching the handling to mbstring or intl or iconv if these module are installed.

The minimum requirement for handling multibyte characters is **mb_substr()** and handling invalid byte sequence.
You can see the cases of a fallback function for **mb_substr()** in the above CMSes.
I answered about handling invalid byte sequence in the following place: [Replacing invalid UTF-8 characters by question marks, mbstring.substitute_character seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13695364/531320)