# replace non utf8 character

Tags: php, mysql, regex, utf-8

i want to allow all utf8 character but want to replace non utf8 with space or -

this is the string

```
Punjab me 1Train k niche 100 Sardar aa gaye..

99 Mar gaye...

1 Bach gaya
```

whatever i do it is not inserting after train

its trimming at train

i have tried these two links

- [Remove non-utf8 characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string)
- [Replacing invalid UTF-8 characters by question marks, mbstring.substitute_character seems ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215050/replacing-invalid-utf-8-characters-by-question-marks-mbstring-substitute-charac)

i want complete utf8 range to insert in mysql and replace the non utf8 with either space or -

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $string);
```

works for above case but when i use hindi/chinese it replaces that too.so i cant use above code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this:**  use only modifier `u` for Unicode

```
    $re = "/[^(\\x20-\\x7F\\n)]+/u";
    $str = "Punjab me 1Train k niche 100 Sardar aa gaye..\n\n99 Mar gaye...\n\n1 Bach gaya";
    $subst = "";

    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ3bH6/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Use str_replace() function:

```
$str = "Punjab me 1Train k niche 100 Sardar aa gaye..";
$rpl_arr = array('', '');
$srch_arr = array(' ', ' ');
$result = str_replace($rpl_arr, $srch_arr);
```