# I'm trying to make sure my string has only valid UTF-8 characters in PHP. How can I do that?

Tags: php, regex, string, unicode, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: replace invalid characters in utf-8 string in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433636/php-replace-invalid-characters-in-utf-8-string-in)

I have a string that has an invalid character in it (it's not UTF-8) such as the following displaying SUB:

[image]

I think it's some kind of foreign invalid character.

Is there a way in PHP to take a string and use `preg_replace` or something else to ensure that I am only using valid UTF-8 characters in my strings, and anything else just gets removed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no invalid UTF-8 characters. There are invalid UTF-8 bytes and byte sequences, which means someone is trying to pull off an encoding attack on your server. These can be validated with `mb_check_encoding` on the coming input data, and immediately failing with 400 Bad Request if you don't get valid UTF-8.

What you have is just the SUBSTITUTE control character, a valid character but unprintable.

> Originally intended for use as a transmission control character to
>   indicate that garbled or invalid characters had been received. It has
>   often been put to use for other purposes when the in-band signaling of
>   errors it provides is unneeded, especially where robust methods of
>   error detection and correction are used, or where errors are expected
>   to be rare enough to make using the character for other purposes
>   advisable.

You can use this regex to get rid of it ([and a few others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes)):

```
$reg = '/(?![\r\n\t])[\p{Cc}]/u';

preg_replace( $reg, "", $str );
```

Comment: UTF-8 characters vs UTF-8 bytes? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Characters = `ABCΩ`. UTF-8 Bytes for those: `0x41 0x42 0x43 0xce 0xa9`. The term `UTF-8 character` does not make sense, UTF-8 is an encoding, something that describes how characters are represented as concrete bytes.

Comment: I am wondering if you meant _there are invalid UTF-8 byte *sequences*_.

Comment: @SalmanA true, I have now added it. There are also plenty of invalid bytes, bytes that are never valid, not even in any sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The [`mb_check_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_check_encoding) function should be able to do this.

```
mb_check_encoding("Jetzt gibts mehr Kanonen", "UTF-8");
```

Note: I haven't tested this.

Comment: This just returns a true or false and doesn't actually detect/tell me which character is valid or remove it. Close though!

Comment: If you need to check which characters are invalid, you could iterate over your string and call `mb_check_encoding` on each character and remove them if it returns false.

Comment: @Kyle you mean each byte, and it would return false for any multi-byte encoding byte then, except the ASCII ones in UTF-8.