# How to decode special characters in UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I am having a `html` with special HTML attributes which are not supporting in html5

currently, I am using

`html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5 | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8'));`

for decoding special attributes. But all the special attributes are converted like this-

> Just reply to this email and let us know the reason � We would really appreciate it! Thank you.

I have tried this one also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433636/php-replace-invalid-characters-in-utf-8-string-in)

I have already wasted one day. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709410/regex-to-detect-invalid-utf-8-string

Comment: @BraveButter suggestion on that link replaces special characters not converted.